# JMeter JMS Point To Point Queue Testing - "No reply message received"

Tags: queue, jms, jmeter, point, reply

I have a JMeter JMS Point to Point test in which I am sending an XML document onto a queue which goes into MongoDB and responds the XML document back.

When I run the test in JMeter I can see through the RedHat logs that the request has gone into Mongo and returned correctly. Although within JMeter, the test fails and I get the message:

> "No reply message received"

If I set the '`communication-style`' to '`Request Only`' the test passes. All my connections are correct and I am using JMeter version 2.11.

I have read on forums to change the jmeter.properties file to enable `JMSSampler.useSecurity.properties=false`. This has not worked.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated,

Thanks,

Kash

Comment: Fixed. I removed the property for queue.Response as well as the JNDI name Receive Queue field. Seemed to do the trick.

Comment: It may help others to see the answer if you move it into an answer and accept it.  Plus you'll have the bonus of gaining some rep - which is always useful!

Comment: Yep - Tried posting an answer yesterday although it said I couldn't answer until x hours later. Cheers for the tip though!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

I removed the property for '`queue.Response`' as well as the JNDI name Receive Queue field.

That seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how it was addressed:

It appears if you are using different queues for request and response, neither of the pre defined attributes to use either messageID or CorrelationID to track response messages does not work.

Therefore don't select any of the two - deselect both. Instead, define a new attribute any the JMS properties for correlation ID as follows

Property name: JMSCorrelationId
Property value: MesgID-${_time(,)}

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed by providing JMSCorrelationId property 
Provide the property value as MsgId-${__time()} 
Note the double underscore as suffix of time function (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)
This will ensure that a correlation Id of current millis is sent on every request and will be matched from response on return.

Note:
1. use communication style as Request Response 
2. do not check any alternate fields checkboxes
3. Provide JNDI name receive queue on which responses are sent